# What are the outcomes from loan sharks interactions?

Tags: battletech

In the Battletech, during the shakedown screen
[image]

you can choose between

1. Sweet talk
2. Ignore
3. Be hostile

Afraid of doing something stupid, I opted to Sweet talk the bank, what resulted in the following outcome:
[image]

In my estimation that is good because I "gained" the **Loan Status : Fair**

The thing is, after browsing all the options, I couldn't find my loan status. So, how would I know if it improved or not?

And what would be the result from the other options in the long run?

Will that affect how much the money the bank will request from me? Can I keep Sweet talking it all the time? Or there is a random chance that the sweet talk will actually cause problem instead of improve my relationship with the bank?

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the banks also props the same message. It might be an introductory window, just for us to get a feel, no stakes or right answers ito it.

Answer (score 2):

As from experience, I can say that 'Educate the banks about their mistake' results in the same outcome.

IIRC the text is completely the same. But more importantly the resulting Loan Status is indeed 'Fair'.

I don't know the result of the 'Ignore the messages' though.